# Prove the implication "if $ac>bc$ and $c>0$, then $a>b$" using the contrapositive

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $ac>bc$ and $c>0$, then $a>b$

I think I would use contrapositive to prove this. But I am not sure proper contrapositive statement.

Is it If $a<b$, then $ac<bc$, and $c<0$.? If so, contrapositive is not a good choice, isn't it?

Comment: Just divide by $c$.

Comment: I am not allowed to use division.

Comment: I see... The reason may be your preparation to study rings and [domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain). You still don't need the contra positive in this setting.

Answer (score 4):

The contrapositive of your statement would be

$$\text{If }\;a\leq b, \text{ then } \;ac\leq bc\;\text{ OR }\;c\leq 0$$

To be "not greater than" means to be "less than or equal to". And the negation of $P$ AND $Q$ is (NOT $P$) OR (NOT $Q$).

Answer (score 3):

If $ac > bc$ and $c > 0$. It follows that $ac-bc = (a-b)c > 0$, because $c>0$ it follows that $a-b>0$, so $a>b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $x>y$ if and only if $x-y>0$. Also $xy>0$ if and only if $x,y$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use induction on $c$ -- assuming that you already know that if $a>b$ and $p>q$ then $a+p>c+q$.

*(Though not after reading user112167's suggestion.)*